# How should dangerous code snippets be published?

Tags: security, concurrency

When discussing (asking/answering questions about, writing blog posts about, etc.) some programming matters, it may be desirable to give source code examples of what you're talking about; but in some cases these snippets may be dangerous, not because they are directly harmful but because they seem to work at first but only set up for problems later. Two examples would be when discussing concurrency issues, where the code works most of the time but rarely and non-deterministically fails, and when discussing security issues, where the code seems to work but can in fact be exploited; and there could be other examples.

It is necessary to be able to discuss such issues, to foster awareness of them at least. However, I am always worried that someone will come from a search engine, barely read the post, copy and paste the snippet and use it for something; more subtly, someone may read the post, try out the code in a test project and confirm it can indeed be exploited (as he is encouraged to do), then some time later reuse the dangerous code, as he has forgotten the code is dangerous and there is no longer a blog post explaining why the code is dangerous around the snippet.

So I am wondering how to mark such code so that no part of it somehow makes it to production (or if it ever does, then the responsible party could not plausibly deny awareness).

One way I came up with is to put:

1. an #error (or similar) directive inside each of the functions, as well as
2. repeated comments warning of the dangerousness of the code (since someone who will try out the code in a test project to confirm the issue will have removed the #error directive).

But since these comments would only clutter up the snippet when reading on the web, I make them the same color as the background (or at least I am trying to; see how I put it in action [here](http://wanderingcoder.net/2011/04/01/arm-memory-ordering/), I incidentally have [a question on doctype.com](http://doctype.com/have-text-shown-picked-up-copypaste) asking how to best do this).

If that seems completely overkill, remember that concurrency (and security) issues are very dangerous so I want to do all I can (within reason) to prevent my snippets from causing issues in real software; I am sometimes comparing this to fissile material handling.

(I honestly don't know whether it would be best suited for programmers.stackexchange.com or here, so I'm asking here first; feel free to move to programmers.stackexchange.com if it turns out it would be better there.)

Answer (score 1):

You make a very good point and I think that you handle it pretty well right now.
However, the #error lines show up in the blog post for me, they are not white.

I think that you shouldn't worry so much about it being picked up by a feed or something like that. If the code is pulled away from the warning message on your blog, it's more important to have the #error lines visible.

But overall, I like your system. I might be good idea to set some standard for this, though, as programmers. 
I would however add a link to the original post explaining *why* it is bad, too. That is way more important than just saying it is.

So to summarize: good idea, we should think of a standard. Make sure to include a link to a why.

Comment: Oh, only the comments are in white; the #error lines do not significantly clutter reading (and serve a nice reminder) so I leave them visible.

Where I am worried about feeds is that my solution can be ugly in them, not that the code will be separated from the post.

Good point on the link back, and we really ought to come up with a standard, even if only for SO.

Comment: Ah, I see. Hadn't picked that up. Well, don't you decide how your RSS feed looks? I guess it wouldn't be to hard to strip the comments starting with /* #error: bad code */ in them. But of course, this would decrease awareness. What I'd do is add a download link for each snippet, where the comments are included. Not everyone would use it, but it would sure help a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, yes, I think it's overkill.

I don't think you need to concern yourself with someone who extracts and uses the code without reading the context in which it's given.  Such a programmer will likely be making so many other mistakes as to render using your code largely irrelevant.

In short they will have and be creating bigger problems.

Comment: I indeed wouldn't concern myself too much in this way if the code snippet was "merely" buggy; such a code snippet would be akin to a grenade, if mishandled it's likely to only harm the one manipulating it. However code having concurrency or security issues is more like a land mine, in that it can harm multiple innocents later, even if they aren't the ones who mishandled the code; so I think such code deserves more proper safety precautions, out of concern for these potential victims.